# using .container and .row responsive classes inside modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I want to have a structure like this inside a bootstrap modal:

[image]

So, In large devices 3 columns with size 4, in medium devices 2 columns with size 6 and in smaller devices 1 column. The pink area its for a small image.

But I dont know how to do this in a good way, its better create many `<ul>`, for example 3 uls, each ul with 1/3 of the options, and put the .col classes in each `<ul>`, or just use 1 `<ul>` and put the .col classes in each list item?

Also I would like ti have the same space between list items both horizontal and vertically.

I already have this structure: https://jsfiddle.net/dehnxj77/, but I dont know how to fix the both issues described above:

- The list items are not appearing with the same space horizontally and vertically
- Also this structre dont have the responsive structure like the image.
- And in the list item Im using  `flex-basis:30%` so that each list item have the same width, but I dont know if this is correct. Maybe with the responsive classes this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
li {margin-top:10px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="row" type="none">
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/pink-color/pink-color-05.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded" style="height:50px;width:50px;display:inline"/>
      <span>option1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/pink-color/pink-color-05.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded" style="height:50px;width:50px;display:inline"/>
      <span>option1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/pink-color/pink-color-05.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded" style="height:50px;width:50px;display:inline"/>
      <span>option1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/pink-color/pink-color-05.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded" style="height:50px;width:50px;display:inline"/>
      <span>option1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/pink-color/pink-color-05.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded" style="height:50px;width:50px;display:inline"/>
      <span>option1</span>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First dot: Apply margin: 0 auto; to your block and a justify-content: space-between to your elements following your flexbox.

Second dot: Inside your modal you already added a container and a row as you are using bootstrap so you can continue with col-md col-sm col-lg as usual and you will save few css adjustments.

Third dot: To have also the same height use max-height on all your elements to have exactly the same height everywhere and adjust with media queries when it's needed.